# GLIBC 2.14 installation error: forced unwind support is required - RHEL 7.5

Tags: python, linux, amazon-ec2, redhat

I have upgraded my RHEL OS from 6.7 to 7.5. After upgrading, I found some issues when trying to run `yum`. Below are the details.

```
# yum repolist

There was a problem importing one of the Python modules                                                                                                                       
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:                                                                                                                   

/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1)                                                                                        

Please install a package which provides this module, or                                                                                                                       
verify that the module is installed correctly.                                                                                                                                

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the                                                                                                                         
current version of Python, which is:                                                                                                                                          
2.6.6 (r266:84292, Aug  9 2016, 06:11:56)                                                                                                                                     
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)]                                                                                                                                       

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to                                                                                                                       
the yum faq at:                                                                                                                                                               
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

---

After getting this error, I just installed python2.7 and GLIBC 2.14. But when I am trying to install GLIBC 2.14 from my current GLIBC version 2.12, it is throwing some error. Below are the steps that I am using to install GLIBC 2.14:

1. `tar xvfz glibc-2.14.tar.gz`
2. `cd glibc-2.14`
3. `mkdir build`
4. `cd build`
5. `../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.14`
6. `make`
7. `sudo make install`
8. `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/glibc-2.14/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

In step5, I am getting error. Below are the details:

```
# ../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.14

checking for forced unwind support... no                                                                                                                                
configure: error: forced unwind support is required
```

I am unaware of this error "unwind support is required".Please let me know how to setup/install forced unwind in Redhat 7.5.

Comment: Dude, that's EXACTLY what is going on here. Did you came up with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

add `libc_cv_forced_unwind=yes` when configure:

```
../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.14 libc_cv_forced_unwind=yes
```

and `make`